# How to track scrolling of TScrollBox in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tscrollbox

Is there any simple way to track scrolling of TScrollbox content with his scrollbars ?
I have several TScrollBox components (each of them has some components inside) and would like to keep them synchronous. If one of scrollboxes scrolled (vertically or horizontally) i need to scroll other scrollboxes synchronously. That is why i need to know when scrollbars positions are changed.
It is strange, but Delphi's TScrollbox component doesn't have such events.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done by adding own Events for the messages `WM_HSCROLL` and `WM_HSCROLL`.
The example is using a interposer class, this could also be done creating by an own component.
If you don't need two Events, you also can implement only one, beeing called in both message procedures.

```
unit Unit3;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TScrollBox=Class(VCL.Forms.TScrollBox)
    procedure WMHScroll(var Message: TWMHScroll); message WM_HSCROLL;
    procedure WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll); message WM_VSCROLL;
  private
    FOnScrollVert: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnScrollHorz: TNotifyEvent;
  public
   Property OnScrollVert:TNotifyEvent read FOnScrollVert Write FonScrollVert;
   Property OnScrollHorz:TNotifyEvent read FOnScrollHorz Write FonScrollHorz;
  End;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    ScrollBox2: TScrollBox;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    Panel4: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure MyScrollHorz(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyScrollVert(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TScollBox }

procedure TScrollBox.WMHScroll(var Message: TWMHScroll);
begin
   inherited;
   if Assigned(FOnScrollHorz) then  FOnScrollHorz(Self);
end;

procedure TScrollBox.WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll);
begin
   inherited;
   if Assigned(FOnScrollVert) then  FOnScrollVert(Self);
end;

procedure TForm3.MyScrollVert(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Scrollbox2.VertScrollBar.Position := Scrollbox1.VertScrollBar.Position
end;

procedure TForm3.MyScrollHorz(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Scrollbox2.HorzScrollBar.Position := Scrollbox1.HorzScrollBar.Position
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ScrollBox1.OnScrollVert := MyScrollVert;
  ScrollBox1.OnScrollHorz := MyScrollHorz;
end;

end.
```