# Two columns for components in a TScrollBox, Delphi

Tags: delphi, tscrollbox

I wanted something like the attached scenario, where user can drag and drop a UI component(TImage) run time (Not from Tool Palette). We were using `TScrollBox` until now. However, I was not able to split it into two parts to accommodate the attached structure.

[image: Components layout]

We can have the second component in a row but it's optional. Also, the two components (row wise) should scroll in sync.

I was thinking to add two TScrollBox and use following code to synchronize vertical scrollbars:
[How to track scrolling of TScrollBox in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788197/how-to-track-scrolling-of-tscrollbox-in-delphi)

However, I couldn't find "Scrollbox1.VertScrollBar.Position" property.

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more the exact problem you're having.  You can place two columns of, say, TEdits into a scrollbox from the Component Palette, and they all scroll in sync fine.  Calculating the position a component should have when it's drag 'n dropped at r/time is trivial, so what's your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Put two TPanels in it. One aligned to right, and size another yourself.

[image]