# How to see if a component is out of view when scrolling in a scrollbox in delphi?

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-2010

I want to change the caption of a panel when it is out of view when scrolling in a TScrollBox. I have a scrollbox where all the all the categories are listed under each other and as the title of each category scrolls past i want the top panel to change to show which category I am currently scrolling through. How exactly can i do this?

Comment: I have this feeling that you are asking the wrong question for what you need to do. So, please edit your question and provide some background for why you need to change the name in the first place, and why it has to be done when the panel is out of view.

Comment: @TomBrunberg is right. Changing the name of a control based on its current visibility in a scroll box sounds *very* strange. Most likely there is a better way to solve your actual problem. Nevertheless, it is very much doable to respond to when a control becomes visible/invisible due to scrolling, as described in my A.

Comment: So you want to change the *caption* of the panel, not the *name*?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes sorry.

Comment: The panel whose caption you want to change, is that panel really a child of the scroll box? Because if so, this seems like a rather dull Q, because when the panel isn't visible, it doesn't matter what caption it has (because you won't see it!). Perhaps you mean that you want to change the caption of some panel outside the scroll box as you scroll the scroll box?

Comment: yes sorry I seem to have the dumb. But yes I want to change the caption of a Panel outside of the scrollbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see if any pixel of a child control `ChildCtrl` currently is visible in the parent `TScrollBox` control named `ScrollBox`, check

```
ScrollBox.ClientRect.IntersectsWith(ChildCtrl.BoundsRect)
```

This is just one definition of "not out of view", however. If you instead want to check if the *entire* control is visible, instead check

```
ScrollBox.ClientRect.Contains(ChildCtrl.BoundsRect)
```

To detect scrolling, you would love a published `OnScroll` property of `TScrollBox`, but unfortunately there is no such property. Instead, you must intercept the scroll messages yourself, as detailed [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17788197/282848).

---

Here is a complete example (just quick and dirty to show how it is done -- in a real app, you would refactor it):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TScrollBox = class(Vcl.Forms.TScrollBox)
    procedure WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll); message WM_VSCROLL;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    lblTitle: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FButtons: TArray<TButton>;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  N = 30;
var
  i, y: Integer;
  btn: TButton;
begin

  // First, populate the scroll box with some sample buttons

  SetLength(FButtons, N);

  y := 10;
  for i := 0 to N - 1 do
  begin
    btn := TButton.Create(ScrollBox1);
    btn.Parent := ScrollBox1;
    btn.Left := 10;
    btn.Top := y;
    btn.Caption := 'Button ' + (i + 1).ToString;
    Inc(y, 3*btn.Height div 2);
    FButtons[i] := btn;
  end;

end;

{ TScrollBox }

procedure TScrollBox.WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll);
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  inherited;

  for i := 0 to High(Form1.FButtons) do
    if Form1.ScrollBox1.ClientRect.Contains(Form1.FButtons[i].BoundsRect) then
    begin
      Form1.lblTitle.Caption := Form1.FButtons[i].Caption;
      Break;
    end;

end;

end.
```

[image: Screenshot of a scroll box containing a vertical array of buttons being scrolled. The caption of the first completely visible button (from the top) is displayed in a label above the scroll box.]

**Don't** forget to set `TScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Tracking` to `True`!

Comment: I have added the system.types unit and still can't find the IntersectsWith command.

Comment: It might not have been introduced in D2010 yet. I don't know exactly when it was introduced. If it is not present, you can always use plain inequalities: `(C.Left < SB.Right) and (C.Right > SB.Left) and (C.Top < SB.Bottom) and (C.Bottom > SB.Top)` where `SB := ScrollBox.ClientRect` and `C := ChildCtrl.BoundsRect` for the first case.